# Show that $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{12}\times \mathbb{Z}_{18}$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism

The group $\mathbb{Z}_{12}\times \mathbb{Z}_{18}$ has 32 elements of order 12 and 54 elements of order 18. Let $G$ be finite commutative group of order $12\times 18$ such that $G$ has 32 elements of order 12 and 54 elements of order 18. To justify whether $G\simeq \mathbb{Z}_{12} \times \mathbb{Z}_{18}$.

Here is what I did.

It is known that, if $G'$ be a commutative group and $|a|=m, |b|=n$ then $G'$ must have at least one element of order lcm$(m,n)$. This means $\mathbb{Z}_{12}\times \mathbb{Z}_{18}$ must have at least one element of order lcm$(12,18)=36$, which eventually happens to be the highest possible order.

Now $\mathbb{Z}_{12}\times \mathbb{Z}_{18}=\langle (1,0), (0,1)\rangle$. Since $G$ has at least one element of order $12$ and at least one element of order 18, so $G$ much have at least one element of order 36. We assume $|a|=12, |b|=18$ in $G$.

Let $f:\mathbb{Z}_{12}\times \mathbb{Z}_{18}\rightarrow G$ be defined by
$f(1,0)=a$ and $f(0,1)=b$. Then $f(\alpha, \beta)=a^{\alpha} b^{\beta}$ for all $(\alpha, \beta)\in \mathbb{Z}_{12}\times \mathbb{Z}_{18}$. Although this is not an isomorphism. and here I got stuck.

Please help how to establish it.

Comment: Z/12 is isomorphic to Z/3xZ/4. Maybe it will help.

Comment: The hypothesis about the numbers of elements of orders $12$ and $18$ hasn't been used yet, but is essential, since there are many Abelian groups of order $12\times18$. <> One approach would be to list the Abelian groups of order $12 \times 18 = 2^3\times3^3$, and to count, or otherwise establish a (mis)match with, the number of elements of orders $12$ and $18$ in each.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would solve this problem. Since $|G|=2^3\cdot3^3$, the maximal $2$-subgroup of $G$ is isomorphic to one of three groups: $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$, $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_4$ or $\mathbb{Z}_8$.

Similarly, the maximal 3-subgroup of $G$ is isomorphic to either
$\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_3$ either
$\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_9$ or
$\mathbb{Z}_{27}$.

Count the number of elements of order $2$, $4$, $3$, $9$ in each case.

$$
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
Order/Group & \mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2 & \mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_4 & \mathbb{Z}_8 \\
\hline
2 & 7 & 3 & 1\\
4 & 0 & 4 & 2\\
\end{array}
$$
$$
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
Order/Group  & \mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_3 & \mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_9 & \mathbb{Z}_{27}\\
\hline
3  & 26& 8 & 3\\
9  & 0 & 18& 5\\
\end{array}
$$

The rest should be clear in my opinion.